# VBA and Word: Cutting a TextBox name to match that of a Bookmark

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I have a Word template with lots of Bookmarks assigned to certain places in it. 
I created a UserForm with TextBoxes to insert text into those places/Bookmarks.

The names of the Bookmarks and TextBoxes match, but the TextBoxes name have "TextBox_" added infront of them.
I also figured out how to loop through all of the TextBoxes (e.g.) of a tab.

Now I wanted to cut the "TextBox_" from the TextBoxes name, while looping, and assign their values to the Bookmarks. I wanted to do this using

```
Replace(ctl.Name, "TextBox_", "")
```

But it wont work. Can somebody tell me what's wrong or help me find a solution? My head is empty right now...

Thanks in advance!

My code so far:

```
Private Sub apply_textboxes()

Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.MultiTab1.Pages(Me.MultiTab1.Value).Controls

    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Replace(ctl.Name, "TextBox_", "")) = ctl.Value

    End If

End Sub
```

(In my UserForm, a button is calling the apply_textboxes sub.)

PS: For some reason, my "Hi" from the beginning gets cut out. So "Hi everyone" from down here!

Comment: "wont work" isn't very descriptive of your actual problem.  Do you get an error?

Comment: `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Replace(ctl.Name, "TextBox_", "")).Range.Text = ctl.Value`

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right! I'm gettin the following error message after pressing the button:

"Compile error: Invalid use of property"
and the following code gets highlighted:

`code`.Bookmarks(Replace(ctl.Name, "TextBox_", "")) =

Comment: After adding the code (.Range.Text) from your second comment, I get the following error message:
"Run-time error '5941': The requested member of the collection does not exist."
And the whole line of code gets highlighted in yellow:
`code`ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Replace(Steuerelement.Name, "TextBox_", "")).Range.Text = Steuerelement.Value

Comment: Ok, I got it working! I had some more TextBoxes without corresponding Bookmarks! So I guess those non-existing Bookmarks were the "members of the collection that did not exist"!
So your solution worked in the end. Thank you so much! :)
What to do next? Are you gonna post that as an answer? Sorry, I'm new...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(Replace(ctl.Name, "TextBox_", "")).Range.Text = ctl.Value
```

You need that `.Range.Text`